# vb.net mantissa and exponent calculation from double

Tags: vb.net, math, exponent, mantissa

Can anyone offer any advice on how to get the mantissa and exponent from a double in VB.net? I know I can do a string parse and some conversion to ints but I wondered if anyone had a mathematical equivalent formula that would allow me to do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to get the "native" mantissa and exponent within the IEEE-754 value? That's actually fairly easy: use [`BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.doubletoint64bits.aspx) to get the value as an integer (which is easier to perform bit operations on) and then see my [article on .NET binary floating point types](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) for which bits are where.

I have some [C# code](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) which extracts the various parts in order to convert it to a precise decimal representation - you could convert the relevant bits of that into VB reasonably easily.

Comment: I just want to get the exponent and manitssa as two seperate integer values.

Comment: user479122: But in what format? Do you mean as *decimal* exponent and mantissa? Or the native base-2 exponent and mantissa?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
Public Function DeclString(ByVal dDegrees As Double) As String
   Dim Flag As String
   Dim ddecimal As Double
   Dim iDegrees As Integer
   If dDegrees < 0 Then Flag = "S" Else Flag = "N"
   iDegrees = Int(Abs(dDegrees))
   ddecimal = (Abs(dDegrees) - iDegrees) * 60 ' + 0.5
   If ddecimal > 59.5 Then iDegrees = iDegrees + 1: ddecimal = 0
   DeclString = Format$(iDegrees, "00") + Flag + Format$(ddecimal, "00")
End Function
```